# Не подключается css файл

Tags: html, css, веб-программирование

```css
.container{
    width: 430px; 
    height: 500px; 
    background-color: #182134; 
    margin: 250px auto 0 auto; 
    text-align: center;
}
```

Возникла проблема, я новичок в web`е. Залил свой первый сайт на бесплатный хостинг, к файлам не подключается css. Путь к css файлу css/style.css.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/style.css">
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Если в адресной строке ввести, то открывает?

Comment: Посмотрите в инспекторе, по какому пути щимится..мб не тот путь

Comment: с чего вы взяли, что не подключается файл стилей? [смотрим скрин](https://i.imgur.com/IOLvDSH.png)

Comment: когда я добавляю внутрь тега атрибут style - все работает, а при подключении файла с таким же содержанием, ничего не происходит, чистый html....

Comment: что-то я вас не пойму.. у вас все подключается, в вашем кастомном css файле всего один класс `.container` и он отлично привязывается к вашей html разметке. ни одного элемента не увидел, где бы вы добавили дополнительно `style`

Answer (score 0):

PHP генерирует HTML страничку и уже ее отсылает пользователю. PHP не может использовать сами css классы, так что нужно добавить тег link что бы сгенерированная HTML страничка могла ссылаться на стили и скачать их уже у пользователя по ссылке.

Что бы добавить этот тег достаточно вывести его с помощью echo:

```
echo "<link rel='stylesheet' href="./css/style.css">";
```

Comment: Не помогло, может быть дело в css файле?

Comment: @ВладКузнецов Приложите пожалуйста ссылку на сайт.

Comment: http://govnokoda.epizy.com

Comment: @ВладКузнецов Попробуйте вот это решение.

Comment: не помогло, и в css вряд ли ошибки есть

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте убрать `/` перед началом пути:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
```

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">

Comment: Все равно не получается(

Answer (score 0):

Обратите внимание по какому пути подключается файл style.css на сайте в инструментах разработчика https://i.stack.imgur.com/DO6MG.png.
Там вы увидите:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main/css/style.css">
```

Попробуйте использовать следующий путь для подключения стилей:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/style.css">
```

Так как к сайту подключены и другие файлы со стилями, частично они будут перебивать друг друга.